# unable to send bigger json(array) data using ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am facing a peculiar problem while sending large data via ajax in mvc.When I send around 500 amount of data its working but when its large its showing an error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

I dont understand why its happening 
My codes are

```
//Reading data from table 
  var imeiUpload = [];

 $('#tblDatas tbody').find("tr").each(function(row, tr) {

        imeiUpload.push({
            Model: $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            Color: $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            Barcode: $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            Barcode2: $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
            UpdatedBy: $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
        });
    });
    //then ajax code

 $.ajax({
        url: ' @Url.Action("InsertImeidata", "Admin")',
        type: 'Post',
        data: JSON.stringify({ imeiModelUpload: imeiUpload }),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {


        },
        error: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            //return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks For Help

Comment: What row throws exception? `$('#tblDatas > tbody > tr').length`?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov no Its okay ,but when i try to send the array as json then its throwing the error

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov i dont understand when i am sending 500 data its working but when it is more than 1k its not working ,why its happening

Comment: Create plunker which will reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found that there was no problem in my ajax or json code everything is fine , The problem was the size of the json data i am sending .And there is a default size in Asp.net application for sending json data

So what I found i have to increase the default size of json data in my application so i added the below  lines

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

then It started working,now i can send big amount of json array.